# Please stop sending me alert to send career invitation to my friends

Tags: discussion, jobs

These days I am getting red ping on top bar (twice, till now) when I am on any stackexchange network. It is just saying "Career Invitations".

---

[image]

---

This making me assume that some company might be trying to contact me through careers network. but when I open the message, it is just telling me to invite my friends.

---

[image]

---

I just don't want to send this invitations. I already invited the friends I knew. Please only ping me if some company is trying to contact me or any thing else which is so important to disturb me.